# error in character comparison

Tags: c++, if-statement

after the switch statement the program compares the characters.in this phase ı have debugged and seen that the first character of string is 111 'o' instead of just 'o' and this causes my program to fail. how can I fix it or where is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main(){

char sentence1[50];
char sentence2[50];
int m,n,k,l;
int i,j,substitution;
cout<<"Enter the first word:"<<endl;
cin>>sentence1;
cout<<"Enter the second word:"<<endl;
cin>>sentence2;
m = strlen(sentence1);
n = strlen(sentence2);
int cost[m+1][n+1];
bool a1,a2;
cost[0][0]=0;

for(i=1;i<m+1;i++){
    cost[i][0]=cost[i-1][0]+2;

}
for(j=1;j<n+1;j++){
    cost[0][j]=cost[0][j-1]+2;

    }




for(i=1;i<m+1;i++){
    for(j=1;j<n+1;j++){

    switch (sentence1[i-1]){
    case 'a':a1=true;
    case 'u':a1=true;
    case 'e':a1=true;
    case 'o':a1=true;
    case 'i':a1=true;
    default:a1=false;
    }
    switch (sentence2[j-1]){
    case 'a':a2=true;
    case 'u':a2=true;
    case 'e':a2=true;
    case 'o':a2=true;
    case 'i':a2=true;
    default:a2=false;

    }
    if(sentence1[i-1]==sentence2[j-1]){substitution=0;

    }
    else if(a1==true && a2==false){substitution=4;}
    else if(a1==false && a2==true){substitution=4;}
    else if(a1==true && a2==true){substitution=3;}
    else if(a1==false && a2==false){substitution=3;}




        cost[i][j]=min(min(cost[i-1][j]+2,cost[i][j-1]+2),cost[i-1][j-1]+substitution);
    }
}





for(i=0;i<m+1;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n+1;j++){

        cout<<cost[i][j]<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}



return 0;   
}
```

Comment: How about using [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/]) to check equality? It doesn't really make sense because a character never really is "just 'o'".

Comment: Uh.. Your naming convention and coding style is a little off.\

Comment: Can you edit your question to show only a couple of lines that demonstrate the problem?

Comment: The Visual Studio debugger is showing you both the decimal ASCII code and its visual representation, that's why you see 111 'o'.

Comment: Without a break statement, every statement from the matched case label to the end of the switch, including the default, is executed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`switch` statements "fallthrough"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Fallthrough) without a `break`.

```
switch (sentence1[i-1]){
case 'a':a1=true; break;
case 'u':a1=true; break;
case 'e':a1=true; break;
case 'o':a1=true; break;
case 'i':a1=true; break;
default:a1=false; break;
}
```

Since this logic is being repeated, consider promoting it to its own function.

```
bool is_a_vowel( char c )
{
  switch (c){
  case 'a':
  case 'u':
  case 'e':
  case 'o':
  case 'i':
     return true;
  default:
     return false;
}
```

Now you can have more readable and consistent code.

```
a1 = is_a_vowel( sentence1[i-1] );
a2 = is_a_vowel( sentence2[j-1] );
```

Comment: Ha, well spotted. I didn't even look that far.